# SafariDriver Selenium sendkeys doesn't work, adds random sign?

Tags: selenium, safari, behat, mink, safaridriver

I'm using Selenium with Mink. I want to open a page in Safari and log in. For that I use

```
/**
 * @When /^(?:i|I) fill in "([^"]*)" with value "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iInputSomethingFormField($selector, $value)
{
    $page = $this->session->getPage();
    sleep(2);
    $elGoogleField = $page->find('css', $selector);

    $elGoogleField->setValue($value);

    sleep(2);
}
```

it works in Chrome, but in Safari, it does put the desired text in the field and adds a random sign apparently. In Selenium, it looks like this:

```
12:36:09.411 INFO - Done: [send keys: 0 [[SafariDriver: safari on MAC
(3D8210C2-66C8-48DC-9A74-639C9CDC8D8B)] -> 
xpath: //html/descendant-or-self::*[@id = 'usr']], [password]]
```

And I have no idea where the char at the end comes from. Login fails of course because there is a wrong sign in the login data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems an issues with safari driver, have you tried to clear the field first? try  to echo the value before filling it to see if you missed something.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in safaridriver, and is now fixed in Safari 11. The fix in WebKit is tracked here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=169733